# Jquery how to update innerhtml of cell after ajax update was succesful

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use the folowing code to update datatables inline. This works fine but I have one problem I can't figur out. At this moment the `cell.data(td.innerHTML);` updates the cell even when the ajax call is not succesfull. How do I change this logic so it will only update my cell data when the ajax call is succesful?

Part of datatable script:

```
  columnDefs: [ 
    

    { "name": "bullets",    "targets": 4 },
    { "name": "notes",    "targets": 5 },
    { "name": "mobcash",    "targets": 6 },
    {
targets: [4,5,6],
createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, rowIdx, colIdx) {
  // 'td' is the DOM node, not the DataTable cell
  td.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
  td.setAttribute('spellcheck', false);
  td.setAttribute('data-old_value', cellData);
  $(td).css('color', rowData.cat_color);
  td.addEventListener("focus", function(e) {
    original = e.target.textContent;
  })
 td.addEventListener("blur", function(e) {
  if (original !== e.target.textContent) {
    // 'cell' is the DataTable cell, not the DOM node:
    let cell = $('#accountTable').DataTable().cell(rowIdx, colIdx);
    cell.data(td.innerHTML);
    let columnName = $('#accountTable').DataTable().settings()[0].aoColumns[colIdx].sName;
    saveInlineEdit(td, columnName, rowData.id, cell.data()); 
    }
  })
}
} ]
```

The script to send the ajax request:

```
   <script>

function saveInlineEdit(editableObj, column, id, newValue) {
  

   var p = loadPrompt();
  var newValuechecked = newValue.replace(/\./g, "");
   console.log("New stripped value",newValuechecked);
  if($.isNumeric(newValue) === false && (column === "bullets" || column === "mobcash")){
  alert("Not updated, wrong input please change your input");
  $(editableObj).css("background","rgba(211, 47, 47 , 0.6)"); 
  return false; }
  
  if(column == "mobcash"){
    var updateValue = newValuechecked}
     if(column != "mobcash"){
    var updateValue = newValue} 
  // send ajax to update value
  $(editableObj).css("background","rgba(56, 142, 60 , 0.6) url(loader.gif) no-repeat right");
  $.ajax({
    url: "update_inlinedata.php",
    cache: false,
    data:'column=' + column + '&value=' + updateValue + '&id=' + id,
    success: function(response)  {
      console.log(response);
      // set updated value as old value
      $(editableObj).attr('data-old_value', updateValue);
      $(editableObj).css("background","");
      p.success('Account data is succesfully updated !');            
    
    
  }
  
 
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try moving this `cell.data(td.innerHTML);` line inside ajax success function .Also , pass `cell` as parameter here `saveInlineEdit(td, columnName, rowData.id, cell.data() ,cell)` and change your `function saveInlineEdit(...` as well.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried to do what you said. But when removing the cell.data(td.innerHTML); it wont pass up the new value. I also do not understand how to move that line to the ajax suc6 function. And why do I need the cell? in the console it gives no good info. Can you be more precise?

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/c218tygv/) you will know where to make changes .

Comment: Take a look at this Fiddle: jsfiddle.net/yqvprkuo It contains 2 URLs, just for testing the ajax. Comment out one of them and test with the other. One is for "success" the other is for "failure". It should give you some guidance on handling the cell updates, I hope.

Comment: Thanks. That works so far. Only thing is that the new typed data still remains in the cell..